# XML URL location

Tags: xml, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am following a JSP tutorial and covering a chapter on XML parsing within the JSP page.  The tutorial does not use Eclipse but I am with Tomcat 8 imported as the server.  The example below shows a URL for the XML file but where do I place the books.xml file in eclipse or how do I configure eclipse to find it?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>JSTL x:parse Tags</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h3>CH24 XML Parse Books Info:</h3>
     <c:import var="bookInfo" url="http://localhost:8081/books.xml" />

     <x:parse xml="${bookInfo}" var="output" />

     <b>The title of the first book is</b>:
     <x:out select="$output/books/book[1]/name" />
     <br>
     <b>The price of the second book is</b>:
     <x:out select="$output/books/book[2]/price" />

  </body>
</html>
```